# zeros function in opencv is not working

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix

I've been trying to learn and use `opencv` Matrices and I'm stucked on a point.

Here is my code,

```
Mat my_img, im_rgb;

im_rgb = imread(imageName, 1);
my_img.create(im_rgb.size(), im_rgb.type()); 

cout << (int)my_img.at<Vec3b>(20,20).val[0] << " first\n";

my_img.zeros(im_rgb.size(), im_rgb.type()); 
cout << (int)my_img.at<Vec3b>(20,20).val[0] << " second \n" ;

my_img.at<Vec3b>(20,20).val[0] = 0;
cout << (int)my_img.at<Vec3b>(20,20).val[0] << third;
```

I read image and I create a `Mat, my_img` which is same type with `im_rgb, CV_8UC3`.

The output is

```
205 first
205 second
0 third
```

After many trial on output, my interpretation is when the my_img created inside of the Matrix is full of `205` and when I call `zeros` function, it is not doing anything. But I can change value of elements of the matrix.

When I try this in matlab, it fulfills the matrix with 0.

I wonder, what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If i remember correctly, `zeros` is a static function of `cv::Mat`, so it does not affect the object. It is used this way:

```
my_img = cv::Mat::zeros(im_rgb.size(), im_rgb.type());
```